# Problems tunning memory consumption and containers number in Hadoop

Tags: java, xml, hadoop, memory-management

I'm trying to configure a Hadoop cluster. The default config work fine, but the resources consumption is poor. For example, the CPU total use in the slaves is slightly above 40%. I want to use the cluster more efficient, and consulting this page:

docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.0.6.0/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap1-11.html

I have a small cluster (1 master and five slaves) and each node have this Hardware:

- 4 Cores
- 8 RAM Gb
- 1 HardDisk of 500Gb

The SO is Ubuntu 14.04 and Hadoop version is 2.5.0.

I try to calculate the values, And obtains that:

Total Available RAM = 8192 - 2024 = 6168 (2Gb for the system)
MIN_CONTAINER_SIZE = 512 (Extracted from table in the above link)
RAM-per-container = 771 -> MAX(MIN_CONTAINER_SIZE, (Total Available RAM) / containers))
Number of Containers: 8 -> MIN(2*CORE, Total Available RAM / MIN_CONTAINER_SIZE)

```
Configuration File      Configuration Setting                   Formula                             Value
yarn-site.xml           yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb     = containers * ram-per-container    6168
yarn-site.xml           yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb    = ram-per-container                 771
yarn-site.xml           yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb    = containers * ram-per-container    6168
mapred-site.xml         mapreduce.map.memory.mb                 = ram-per-container                 771
mapred-site.xml         mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb              = 2 * ram-per-container             1542
mapred-site.xml         mapreduce.map.java.opts                 = 0.8 * ram-per-container           616.8
mapred-site.xml         mapreduce.reduce.java.opts              = 0.8 * 2 * ram-per-container       1233.6
yarn-site.xml (check)   yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb       = 2 * ram-per-container             1542
yarn-site.xml (check)   yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts      = 0.8 * 2 * ram-per-container       1
```

233.6

This config, and some variants of the same, didn't work, and I get error like that

```
14/12/09 17:17:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1418155570046_0004_m_000060_1, Status : FAILED
Container [pid=5808,containerID=container_1418155570046_0004_01_000081] is running beyond physical memory limits. Current usage: 827.2 MB of 771 MB physical memory used; 1.6 GB of 1.9 GB virtual memory used. Killing container.
Dump of the process-tree for container_1418155570046_0004_01_000081 :
    |- PID PPID PGRPID SESSID CMD_NAME USER_MODE_TIME(MILLIS) SYSTEM_TIME(MILLIS) VMEM_USAGE(BYTES) RSSMEM_USAGE(PAGES) FULL_CMD_LINE
    |- 5815 5808 5808 5808 (java) 580 27 1706360832 211455 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN -Xmx1024M -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_store/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1418155570046_0004/container_1418155570046_0004_01_000081/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1418155570046_0004/container_1418155570046_0004_01_000081 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.4.1.103 57356 attempt_1418155570046_0004_m_000060_1 81 
    |- 5808 4341 5808 5808 (bash) 0 0 14008320 303 /bin/bash -c /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.metrics.log.level=WARN  -Xmx1024M -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop_store/tmp/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache/application_1418155570046_0004/container_1418155570046_0004_01_000081/tmp -Dlog4j.configuration=container-log4j.properties -Dyarn.app.container.log.dir=/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1418155570046_0004/container_1418155570046_0004_01_000081 -Dyarn.app.container.log.filesize=0 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,CLA org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild 10.4.1.103 57356 attempt_1418155570046_0004_m_000060_1 81 1>/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1418155570046_0004/container_1418155570046_0004_01_000081/stdout 2>/usr/local/hadoop/logs/userlogs/application_1418155570046_0004/container_1418155570046_0004_01_000081/stderr  

Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
```

Or also I get Java Heaps errors.

The same applications didn't fail with the default configure.

What is wrong whit that?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: I don't get it, if the RAM needed by your container is not enough to fit into 771 mb, why don't you just increase it? If memory is your bottleneck, then optimize your memory usage or buy more ram.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut, thanks for your comment. If I try to change the `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` value, for example, up to 1024 or 2048, I get others errors (Java Heaps errors). My Question point to know what is a more suitable value for the config parameters, with the available hardware. Sorry for the unclearly form of my explanation.